# Clipboard object handling

Tags: c#

I use the windows clipboard in my program.I use something like

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject(); //save old data
DoSomethingWithClipboard();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data); //Set old data back}
```

This runs well, but after the second time I click my button my old data is gone I think it overrides something after the second time it uses `IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();`.

Comment: Please ask a specific question and post code.

Comment: GetDataObject retrieves the data, SetDataObject sets it - are you doing things back to front. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdataobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: First I retrieve the old data I fill it with new data in my method and in the end I set the old data back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion trying to manipulate the clipboard like this is a bad idea.

- It's volatile so the contents could have changed since you started your operation.
- The data in the clipboard will belong to other applications and may not restore correctly causing instability.
- You shouldn't be changing the clipboard without the users consent.

That said, here's some **untested** code that should do what you want.

```
public class ClipBoardBackupRestore
{
    Dictionary<string, object> clipboardContents = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public void Backup()
    {
        clipboardContents.Clear();

        IDataObject clipboardDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        foreach (string format in clipboardDataObject.GetFormats())
        {
            clipboardContents.Add(format, clipboardDataObject.GetData(format));
        }
    }

    public void Restore()
    {
        DataObject clipboardDataObject = new DataObject();

        foreach (string format in clipboardContents.Keys)
        {
            clipboardDataObject.SetData(format, clipboardContents[format]);
        }

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipboardDataObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use the clipboard because I get rtf format from the database I have to fill it in a richtextbox get the formatted rtf from the richtextbox paste it in word and then restore the clipboard

Comment: I don't know the ins and outs of your solution so it's hard for me to comment fully, but having done similar things before I'd say the clipboard is definitely the easiest and quickest way to do what you want but it can certainly be done without touching the clipboard at all.